# ASP.NET web service for Android, iOS and BB

Tags: asp.net, android, web-services, ios, blackberry

I am creating a web service in ASP.NET that needs to be accessed from Android, iOS and BB. The big stickler here is that I do *not* want to use any libraries on these mobile platforms to read the transmitted data. I know that Android has a JSON parser built-in, but iOS does not. I also know that WCF-format is out, since none of them read that.

Is my only choice using a proprietary format for the transmitted data to be read by these devices? Has anyone found a good (native) format for the communication with the service across the platforms that doesn't involve creating a proprietary format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JSON. It's built into Android and [Blackberry](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/org/json/me/package-summary.html), and there are [Objective-C libraries](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to use it with iOS. It's light and compact and easy to create and parse.

Comment: While you are right to a degree (I did go with JSON), please note that BlackBerry 4.6 and 4.5 (the most targeted) DO NOT include JSON libraries. You have to use 3rd party classes to get this done (which are easily found, but it has to be noted).

Answer (score 1):

What is "WCF-format"? ASP.NET web services use SOAP by default.  WCF services can also be configured to use SOAP or to be RESTful.  SOAP is just XML so any framework with an XML parser should do, and with WCF REST you can work with XML or JSON easily.

Comment: SOAP/XML did the job for me.  Of course all I pass back and forth are strings, but still..  no issues with going from Android/Java to XML Web Service and back.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use JSON. Although iPhone SDK doesn't have a built-in SDK library, you will easily find an inplematation ([json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) for example). The big benefit willbe that you could configure WCF to output bare JSON, which will be easily understood by all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

REST has less overhead than SOAP, since it is just an HTTP GET/POST/PUT/DELETE.  If you need something more than simple CRUD however, SOAP may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry doesn't have built-in support for JSON as far as I know, at least not for older models. iOS doesn't have built-in support for any of the web services so you have to parse the XML manually if you don't use any third party library. I would say you if you want, you can use JSON with some borrowed library. I chose SOAP because I can use it across platforms including some really old windows mobile phones and I want to use as less third party lib as possible.